# Continuously changing bundle coloring in D3 bundle layout

Tags: javascript, svn, graphics, d3.js, bundle-layout

Aloha,

is there any possibility to make the bundles in [this](http://bl.ocks.org/1044242) visualization:

[image]

... look just like the bundles in [that](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/mbostock/iv/dependency-tree.html) visualization

[image]

?

I have no idea how to achieve this in d3.

EDIT 1:
Obviously I have to write a custom interpolator. How can I extend the bundle interpolator to additionally interpolate between two colors without changing the d3 library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither SVG or Canvas support stroking a gradient along a path. The way that my [dependency tree visualization](https://github.com/mbostock/dependency-tree) is implemented is as follows. For each path:

1. Start with a basis spline (see [Hierarchical Edge Bundling](http://www.win.tue.nl/~dholten/papers/bundles_infovis.pdf)).
2. Convert to a piecewise cubic Bézier curve (see [BasisSpline.segments](https://github.com/mbostock/dependency-tree/blob/master/geom/BasisSpline.js#L102-148)).
3. Convert to a piecewise linear curve (*i.e.*, polyline; see [Path.flatten](https://github.com/mbostock/dependency-tree/blob/master/geom/Path.js#L236-292)).
4. Split into equal-length linear segments (see [Path.split](https://github.com/mbostock/dependency-tree/blob/master/geom/Path.js#L294-352)).

Once you have these linear segments, you color each segment by computing the appropriate color along the gradient. So, the first segment is drawn green, the last segment is drawn red, and the intermediate segments are drawn with a color somewhere in-between. It might be possible to combine steps 2-4 by sampling the basis spline at equidistant points, but that will require more math.

My dependency tree is implemented in Canvas, but you could achieve the same effect in SVG by creating separate path elements (or line elements) for each segment of constant color. You might get slightly better performance by combining segments of the same color.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know what I have to do.

Comment: Yeah, you can use linear gradients for linear segments (and approximate it for other paths), but that technique doesn't generalize to arbitrary splines.

Comment: Hi @mbostock great explanation, it there a way to use this with d3? What I am planing to do is create my curves in an SVG then for each curve I will associate a path object and use it to check for intersection. However, it seems memory consuming. I can combine it with the queue.js library. I am wandering if there is a better way using d3js?